# PHP out of memory with CDataProviderIterator (Yii)

Tags: php, yii

I am having an out of memory issue with my PHP script on the Yii framework. I've tried to do quite a bit of debugging. I'm using a CDataProviderIterator because the Yii documentation says this about it:

> For example, the following code will iterate over all registered users (active record class User) without running out of memory, even if there are millions of users in the database.

This code iterates over around 1.5 million records and it runs out of memory in its attempt. I'm looking for any kind of help of why it might be doing this. Thanks!

```
public function foo($model, $relations) {
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider($model, array('criteria' => $model->dbCriteria));
    $iterator = new CDataProviderIterator($dataProvider, 200);
    $this->modelsToArray($iterator, $relations, $model_as_array = array());
}

public function modelsToArray($model, $relations, $model_as_array = array()) {
    $preparedRelations = $this->prepareRelations($relations);
    if (is_null($model))
    {
        return array();
    }
    $model_as_array = array();
    if (get_class($model) === 'CDataProviderIterator') {
        foreach ($model as $row) {
            $model_as_array[] = $this->modelsToArrayHelper($preparedRelations, $row);
        }   
    }
    else {
        $model_as_array[] = $this->modelsToArrayHelper($preparedRelations, $model);
    }

    return $model_as_array;
}

private function modelsToArrayHelper($relations, $listOfModels) {
    $listOfArrayModels = array();

    if(!is_array($listOfModels)){
        return $this->modelToArrayHelper($listOfModels, $relations);
    }
    foreach ($listOfModels as $index => $model)
    {
        $listOfArrayModels[$index] = $this->modelToArrayHelper($model, $relations);
    }
    return $listOfArrayModels;
}

private function modelToArrayHelper($model, $relations){
    $model_as_array = $this->processAttributes($model);
    foreach ($relations as $relationIndex => $relation)
    {
        $relationName = is_string($relationIndex) ? $relationIndex : $relation;
        if(empty($model->$relationName)) 
            continue;
        if ($model->relations()[$relationName][0] != CActiveRecord::STAT)
        {
            $subRelations = is_array($relation) ? $relation : array();
            $model_as_array[$relationName] = $this->modelsToArrayHelper($subRelations, $model->$relationName);
        }
        else
        {
            $model_as_array[$relationName] = $model->$relationName;
        }
    }

    return $model_as_array;
}
```

Comment: quick fix while i try to recreate this 

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

Comment: you are converting the $iterator to an array so it will need more ram !
i think thats whats causing the issue

Comment: did u solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

i believe you are trying to convert the CDataProviderIterator to a Php array.
so for placing the array you need more memory

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

this sets the use of ram to max usage

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

this sets the ram usage to 512 Mb

Can you make your code like this just to make sure you are not using too much ram

```
public function foo($model, $relations) {
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider($model, array('criteria' => $model->dbCriteria));
    $iterator = new CDataProviderIterator($dataProvider, 200);
    $preparedRelations = $this->prepareRelations($relations);
    foreach ($iterator as $row) {
           print_r ($this->modelsToArrayHelper($preparedRelations, $row));
    }   
}
```

and

Comment: So I'm not trying to convert the CDataProviderIterator to a php array. I'm converting each record that it iterates over to an array. In reality, this should preserve memory because of the way CDataProviderIterator does not store all the objects in memory. In my case it will only store 200 model objects in memory at a time and then it will drop them. I tried your solution and now I just don't get a response back. My main question is why this is taking up so much memory when in reality, it should be taking up less memory based on the claims in the documentation.

Comment: Because it looks like you are trying to store 1.5 million arrays inside $model_as_array

Comment: yes i can see that but what are you doing with  $model_as_array;

Comment: I am trying to store 1.5 million objects inside the $model_as_array array. What I'm doing with $model_as_array is converting it to JSON and sending it back to the client. Setting the memory limit like that does not seem like good practice to me. I tried it anyway and it did not work. I found a solution to just convert the array to JSON as I go, calling unset on the object after I convert it to preserve memory. This works and actually preserves memory instead of just changing the memory limit. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: nice , can u share a sample code for your solution so that the community could also benefit .Please add it as an answer